# "Ich bin fertig mit der Arbeit" or "Ich habe fertig die Arbeit"?

Tags: grammar, translation, grammatical-case, spelling

> Ich bin fertig mit der Arbeit.

or

> Ich habe fertig die Arbeit.

if there is more explication for "fertig"

Comment: Is your last line a question?

Comment: Just because you seem to be fairly new and have never accepted an answer: Do you know that you can accept answers to your questions? It marks that you are satisfied with an answer and helps identifying which questions need additional anwers and which don't. Also, it gives 2 reputation points to you and 15 to the answerer, so it is also nice to do so. Of course, if you think there could be better answers, then don't accept. And you can always accept a different answer later, if someone writes a better answer.

Comment: "ich habe fertig" habe ich nur bei Trapattoni gehört: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCFj9lf8IQE

Answer (score 5):

"Die Arbeit" ist weiblich. Und es heißt "mit etwas fertig sein" oder "fertig mit etwas sein".

Also heißt es

> Ich bin mit der Arbeit fertig.
>
> Ich bin fertig mit der Arbeit.

---

**Aktualisierung**:

Es gibt auch "etwas fertig [Partizip Perfekt eines Verbes] haben"

Also ist

> Ich habe die Arbeit fertig [gemacht].
>
> Es hat das Buch fertig [gelesen, geschrieben, ...].

auch in Ordnung.

Wobei es bei Letzter um eine konkret fassbare Arbeit, wie einen Aufsatz schreiben, ein Bild malen oder das Setzen einer Mauer handeln sollte. Wenn es sich um einen Arbeitstag handelt, ist die erste Variante angebrachter.

Comment: `Ich hab fertig ...` darf nur Trapattoni benutzen: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCFj9lf8IQE [3:23] ;-)

Comment: Double jeopardy  "Fertig bin ich mit der Arbeit."

Comment: Oder nach Joda: Mit der Arbeit ich fertig bin.

Comment: Hachja, die deutsche Sprache. Hier noch eine Variante: Mit der Arbeit bin ich fertig.

Comment: Also "Es hat die das Buch fertig" ist Unsinn. Es heisst "Er hat das Buch fertig [gelesen]". Oder vielleicht "Es (das Kind) hat die Bücher fertig gelesen".

Comment: Wenn es ein Schreiber ist: "Wie weit ist er mit dem neuen Buch. Er hat es fertig." @PMF

Comment: @alk: Ok, das geht. Wobei dann eher noch besser "Er hat es abgeschlossen" oder "Es ist fertig" wäre.

Comment: „Hast Du Deine Hausaufgaben fertig?“ may not be the best choice of wording, but is certainly used.

Answer (score 1):

The correct expression for nouns is *mit etwas fertig sein*. So:

> Ich bin mit der Arbeit fertig.
>
> Ich bin mit dem Training fertig.
>
> Ich bin mit der Pressekonferenz fertig.
>
> Ich bin mit der Antwort noch nicht fertig. (Es kommt noch etwas.)

However, sometimes in rare cases you can hear ‘ich habe fertig.’ Just like that, just as a fixed expression. This goes back to 1998 and the Italian trainer of Bayern Munich, Giovanni Trapattoni, who [famously exploded in a press conference](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OCFj9lf8IQE) and singlehandedly introduced the idioms ‘Flasche leer’ and ‘ich habe fertig’ into the German language. The latter was his line before storming out of the room. However, you will very rarely if at all attach something to the *ich habe fertig.* It typically only stands by itself.

---

Sometimes, compound verbs are used that are formed out of *fertig* + verb, e.g. *fertigmachen.* These can be put into past tense in the way you expect them, and they typically require *haben.* Therefore, the following is valid, too:

> Ich habe *fertiggeschrieben*.

Comments noted the sentence ‘Hast du deine Hausaufgaben fertig?’ (‘Did you complete your homework?’) which is in fact missing the verb bit; it can be extended to:

> Hast du deine Hausaufgaben *fertiggemacht*?

---

> Jetzt: Ich habe fertig.

Comment: +1 for Giovanni Trapattoni